# I have a problem with disappearing "dynamic" form fields! (html + jquery)

Tags: html, jquery, firebase

I am currently working on a form, within a modal.

My objective is to implement dynamic fields that the user can add and remove.

*its also worth mentioning that the value of these "dynamic fields" later will be exported to a

firebase database!

For now the fields show up but, when i execute the delete/remove function to a recently

added field everything disapears.

This is the html section

```
<div class="bg-modal">
        <div class="modal-contents">
    
            <div class="close li:hoover">+</div>
           
            <!-- validation todo -->
            <form class="input-modal" id="kundInfo">
                <br>    
                <input class="input-modal" type="text" placeholder="name" id="userName" required>

                <input class="input-modal" type="email" placeholder="e-mail" id="userEmail" required>
                 
                <textarea class="input-modal" name="meddelande" placeholder="Övrig information" id="userMessage"></textarea>

                <select class="input-modal" id="deliveryTown" value="">
                    <option value="default">Välj leveransort</option>
                    <option value="Stockholm">Stockholm</option>
                    <option value="Göteborg">Göteborg</option>
                    <option value="Kalmar">Kalmar</option>
                </select>
                <br>

                <div id="dynamic-items">
                <input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="text" name="artikel[]" placeholder="Artikel">
                <input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="number" name="kvantitet[]" placeholder="kvantitet">
                <input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="button" value="Lägg till" id="add">
                <!-- (original submit button)
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                -->
                </div>
                
                <br>
                <select class="input-modal" id="produktKategori" value="">
                    <option value="default">Välj inköpskategori</option>
                    <option value="trävaror">Trävaror</option>
                    <option value="mur&puts">Mur & puts</option>
                    <option value="mark&trädgård">Mark & trädgård</option>
                    <option value="vvs">VVS</option>
                    <option value="våtrum">Våtrum</option>
                    <option value="verktyg">Verktyg</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button class="input-modal" id="Skicka" type="submit">Skicka</button>
            </form>

            <div class="alert">Ditt förfrågan är skickad!</div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
```

...and this is the jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    
    $("#add").click(function (e){
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#dynamic-items').append(
            
        '<input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="text" name="artikel[]" placeholder="Artikel">'+
        '<input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="number" name="kvantitet[]" placeholder="kvantitet">'+
        '<input type="button" name="delete[]" value="delete" id="delete"/></div>'
            
        );

    });


    $('body').on('click', '#delete',function (e){
        event.preventDefault()
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing the opening <div> tag for the inputs in the click-function for add: It should be '<div><input class="dynamic-input-fields" instead of '<input class="dynamic-input-fields". Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a3fopv75/

Comment: That seem to be it, worked right away.  
Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Hello again @matthias_h ,
Thanks ones again for helping me out.
I hope i'm not  being a pain in the *** right now
but i kind of stumbled upon another problem related to this topic,
i cannot seem to export the values of the dynamically generated fields?
Seems like firebase can't get the values as an array, and i haven't been able to generate unique id's for some weird reason.

i've posted it as a new question here (including code snippets):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653330/problem-with-exporting-dynamically-user-frontend-generated-form-fields-to-fire

Answer (score 0):

The html string not have `<div>` on start.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#dynamic-items').append(

      '<div><input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="text" name="artikel[]" placeholder="Artikel">' +
      '<input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="number" name="kvantitet[]" placeholder="kvantitet">' +
      '<input type="button" name="delete[]" value="delete" id="delete"/></div>'

    );

  });


  $('body').on('click', '#delete', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-modal">
  <div class="modal-contents">

    <div class="close li:hoover">+</div>

    <!-- validation todo -->
    <form class="input-modal" id="kundInfo">
      <br>
      <input class="input-modal" type="text" placeholder="name" id="userName" required>

      <input class="input-modal" type="email" placeholder="e-mail" id="userEmail" required>

      <textarea class="input-modal" name="meddelande" placeholder="Övrig information" id="userMessage"></textarea>

      <select class="input-modal" id="deliveryTown" value="">
        <option value="default">Välj leveransort</option>
        <option value="Stockholm">Stockholm</option>
        <option value="Göteborg">Göteborg</option>
        <option value="Kalmar">Kalmar</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <div id="dynamic-items">
        <input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="text" name="artikel[]" placeholder="Artikel">
        <input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="number" name="kvantitet[]" placeholder="kvantitet">
        <input class="dynamic-input-fields" type="button" value="Lägg till" id="add">
        <!-- (original submit button)
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                -->
      </div>

      <br>
      <select class="input-modal" id="produktKategori" value="">
        <option value="default">Välj inköpskategori</option>
        <option value="trävaror">Trävaror</option>
        <option value="mur&puts">Mur & puts</option>
        <option value="mark&trädgård">Mark & trädgård</option>
        <option value="vvs">VVS</option>
        <option value="våtrum">Våtrum</option>
        <option value="verktyg">Verktyg</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="input-modal" id="Skicka" type="submit">Skicka</button>
    </form>

    <div class="alert">Ditt förfrågan är skickad!</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Hans!
That seemed to be it indeed :)